# MySQL script fails to drop table even though foreign key is dropped on a previous step

Tags: mysql

On a previous step I create add a column and the following foreign key:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_pricingRuleSetId FOREIGN KEY (`set_id`) REFERENCES dynamic_pricing_rule_set (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Then I execute the revert script which is pretty much the following

```
ALTER TABLE submarket_archive_properties DROP FOREIGN KEY  fk_dynamicPricingSetId; 
ALTER TABLE submarket_archive_properties DROP COLUMN `dynamic_pricing_set`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dynamic_pricing_rule_set;
```

Executing the second sql script I get the following error

```
Query OK, 143 rows affected (0.37 sec)             
Records: 143  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 143 rows affected (0.17 sec)             
Records: 143  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

ERROR 1217 (23000) at line 7 in file:'3.7_to_3.7.1.revert.sql': Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

This is possibly something pretty obvious, but I am not very good at MySQL and am not able to spot it

Comment: Maybe there are other foreign key constraints.

Comment: Pf, you are right. I knew it was something stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some other table have this table reference, so first either you need to delete all records that child table or delete reference.

You can get that table by below query-

```
SELECT constraint_Schema AS mydb, table_name AS child_table,constraint_name AS foreign_key_name, referenced_table_name AS master_table 
FROM information_Schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE constraint_Schema='mydb' AND referenced_table_name='dynamic_pricing_rule_set';
```

Note: change mydb as your db here.

This is the clean procedure.

But if you don't bother your data consistency then you can follow below procedure also-

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dynamic_pricing_rule_set;
set foreign_key_checks=1;
```

Note: We should not follow it if we want to keep our data consistent.